# append an element to another one and append all of them to another element

Tags: jquery

I want to create a `div` and append one `ul` (with a class) and one `h5` (with text) to it. then, append that `div` to another element.

I think this code should do it:

```
$("div").addClass( "nice" )
    .append( $("ul").addClass("myclass") )
    .append( $("h5").text("heading") )
    .appendTo( $("#another_div") );
```

but it doesn't work and browser crashes!

How? (i know i can use `$("div").html()`, but i don't like it!)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that by using "div" and "ul" as your selectors, jQuery is searching the dom instead of creating elements.  Try this:

```
$("<div></div>").addClass( "nice" )
    .append( $("<ul></ul>").addClass("myclass") )
    .append( $("<h5></h5>").text("heading") )
    .appendTo( $("#another_div") );
```

Answer (score 2):

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/kzLmp/

```
$(function(){
    $("<div>").addClass( "nice" )
    .append( $("<ul>").addClass("myclass") )
    .append( $("<h5>").text("heading") )
    .appendTo( $("#another_div") );
});
```